# Simple RequireJS Structure with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

My structrure is below. I have a very simple example of requireJS but i stack to the most important. I can't seperate angular controller from bootstrap.js file. 
I want to help me complete my first example to understand it. Thank you

- javascripts/bootstrap.js
- javascripts/main.js
- index.php

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>RequireJS</title>
<script data-main="javascripts/main" src="require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="hello">
    {{sayHello()}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "javascripts",
paths: {
    'angular': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min'
},
shim: {
    'angular': {
        exports: 'angular'
    }
},
deps: ['./bootstrap']
});
```

bootstrap.js

```
require(["angular"],function(angular){
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller("hello",
    function($scope) {
        $scope.sayHello = function() {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
);
return app;
})
```

Comment: where did you bootstrap angular itself? something like  ```angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);```

Comment: Give me an example where to include it

Comment: check my setup here old [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PwazojVEOJEY8dJKQUvT?p=preview)

Comment: This example was very usefull

Now... if i need one page to load only "MainCtrl" without clicker... what i have to do??

can we seperate this
require(['angular','app', 'MainCtrl','clicker'], function (angular) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this stripped down version of the plnkr in the comments
[**updated plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kyo5c352AsD5AyIPYMgg?p=preview)

The setup is simple, there is one entry point called `config.js`.

This is where you bootstrap angular to the document.

If you were using jquery, lodash, etc those would be loaded in the `config.js`

Similar to using `ng-app`.

This is also the location where you require the global angular object, your app namespace and other components such as your controller.

```
require(['angular', 'app', 'MainCtrl'], function(angular) {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

The next is the `app.js` which setups angular module, you can do site wide routing and other configs, and dependencies such `ngRoute` would go here.

```
define(['angular'], function(angular) {
  return angular.module('app', []);
});
```

Finally we have `MainCtrl.js` its  where you do your controller logic.

```
define(['app'], function(app) {
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    this.name = "Hello Angularjs";
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks... Here is my next question... The config.js file requires all controllers,directives,factories for all project... so if i have another page, where i need only some of them... should i create another config file?

Comment: I want to bootstrap my app to each page with different directives,controllers and factories... (I don't use routing, only dirrerent pages)

Comment: Im not sure i follow.. do you have multiple index pages?

Comment: if you have different php files you could do that or you could make a template based with only one index.php and then about.php or contact.php etc would be loaded into your index.php based on url...